# Hobby tier hobby-dev postgres on Heroku data vanishes after a while

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I used node.js to write an game, I used Postgres package for node called pg.
Everything I insert into the database works. The inserted data can be retrieved as well. The data still exists even after restarting the dyno.

The inserted data is not more than a couple of rows.

But after a day or so the inserted data does not exist in the table. I read the Heroku docs but could not find why it happens.

Whats going wrong?

I am using free tier of Heroku with hobby-dev plan for Postgres.

**Edit:**

The code of my database is as follows:

```
// I need to delete the rows from the database which are one day old, one week old and the third table not at all old
var flushTable = function(tableName, dateObj, callback) {
    var client = null, query = null;
    var strDate = getDateString(dateObj);
    client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    query = client.query('DELETE FROM '+tableName+' WHERE latest_date<TO_DATE(\''+strDate+'\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\');', function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        client.end();
        callback();
    });
};
var createNonExistent = function(tableName, callback) {
    var client = null, query = null;
    client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    query = client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  '+tableName+' (username VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, score INTEGER NOT NULL, latest_date DATE NOT NULL, latest_time TIME NOT NULL, ip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log('Table Created');
        client.end();
        callback();
    });
}
var readFromTable = function(tableName, callback) {
    flushTable(tableName, new Date(), function(){
        var client = null, query = null;
        client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
        client.connect();
        query = client.query('SELECT * FROM '+tableName+' ORDER BY score DESC, latest_date DESC, latest_time DESC;', function(err, result){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                client.end();
                return;
            }
            console.log('Read values');
            console.log(result.rows);
            client.end();
            callback(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the error, I was not changing the date in the code, so I added another function called flushAll() and I called it before reading and writing.

The function flushAll() correctly deletes the tables unlike the delete done in the readTable() function.

Here is the modified code:

```
var flushTable = function(tableName, dateObj, callback) {
    var client = null, query = null;
    var strDate = getDateString(dateObj);
    client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    query = client.query('DELETE FROM '+tableName+' WHERE latest_date<TO_DATE(\''+strDate+'\',\'YYYY-MM-DD\');', function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        client.end();
        callback();
    });
};
var createNonExistent = function(tableName, callback) {
    var client = null, query = null;
    client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    query = client.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  '+tableName+' (username VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, score INTEGER NOT NULL, latest_date DATE NOT NULL, latest_time TIME NOT NULL, ip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);', function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log('Table Created');
        client.end();
        callback();
    });
}
var flushAll = function(callback) {
    flushTable('today',new Date(), function(){
        var dateObj = new Date();
        var strDate = getDateString(dateObj);
        while (dateObj.getDay() != 0) {
            dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()-1);
        }
        flushTable('thisweek',new Date(), function(){
            callback();     
        });
    });
}
var readFromTable = function(tableName, callback) {
    var client = null, query = null;
    client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
    client.connect();
    query = client.query('SELECT * FROM '+tableName+' ORDER BY score DESC, latest_date DESC, latest_time DESC;', function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            client.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log('Read values');
        console.log(result.rows);
        client.end();
        callback(result);
    });
};
exports.readLeaderBoards = function(callback) {
    var boards = [];
    flushAll(function(){
        createNonExistent('alltime', function(){
            createNonExistent('thisweek', function(){
                createNonExistent('today', function(){
                    readFromTable('today', function(result) {
                        boards['today'] = result.rows;
                        readFromTable('thisweek', function(result) {
                            boards['thisweek'] = result.rows;
                            readFromTable('alltime', function(result) {
                                boards['alltime'] = result.rows;
                                console.log(boards['today']);
                                callback(boards);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
```